# "Do lunch" vs. "have lunch": question closure

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, specific-question

I realise there's a lot of this lately, and I'm about to add to it, but here goes:

[Difference between "I am doing lunch" and "I am having lunch"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94674/difference-between-i-am-doing-lunch-and-i-am-having-lunch)

A perfectly valid question. The single answer given is a start, as is my comment, but put together they are still insufficient and unreferenced. (The poster admits this: "I've answered below with the only meaningful distinction I can think of.") Question closed, as exact duplicate. The "exact duplicate" thread has no mention of lunch in the question, but it's sort of about food-type things. Fine. There is one single answer: it is, equally, a start, but insufficient to entirely answer the question at hand; and it does indeed mention lunch, but only to state that "do lunch", "have lunch" and "eat lunch" are all English phrases. The best advice given is "just learn them one by one" - but nothing is said about their differences.

The most frustrating thing about this is not that none of the five closevoters spent the 10 seconds necessary to realise that the threads were not duplicates and their single answers were insufficient for either question, but that one of those closevoters was also the author of *both* of these answers. Words fail me.

Please reopen this thread.

Comment: I don't see the problem with that one. Robusto gave a precise answer, but apparently realised later that he himself had given a more generic answer over a year and a half ago. Do you really want ELU to spent forever going over and over the same ground?

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I said, what you call the 'generic' answer doesn't even address the question. And the 'precise' answer is a little less precise even than my throwaway comment, which I didn't post as an answer because it was imprecise and unreferenced. There is *no* cause for closing the question here. The entire force of two threads' worth of "answers" to that question is Robusto's intuition, which doesn't even agree with mine. How about waiting for another opinion, or a reference? Or at least, if you insist that it be closed, find a non-bogus reason to close it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Not so. Robusto downvoted (we may conjecture that he remembered having addressed the matter a year and a half ago); and then, after I protested that that answer did not address OP's question, he posted his answer. It's a legitimate question and deserves a legitimate answer - and for the honour of the site an answer that at least consolidates Robusto's remarks with those of other commenters.

Comment: @Billy: I'm not going to suggest that my understanding of what an idiomatic expression "means" is any more valid than yours. As it happens, I'm with Robusto in thinking *"Doing lunch" is slang for meeting someone and having lunch together*, and it never occurred to me anyone would think differently. But if you do, why did you not post your *with a secondary purpose in mind* as an answer? Trivial distinctions like this are unlikely to be found in dictionaries - if you don't post what *you* think so people can vote on it, why do you expect others to do this?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not post my intuition because, as I said, I did not have a reference yet, and it was only my intuition. I do not consider my intuition an 'answer', but a 'comment', in the plain English meanings of those words. In any case, *I* am not relevant. The question is not duplicate, and the answer is contentious, incomplete and unreferenced, and now nobody else is allowed to improve upon it. Given these facts, why on earth is this question being allowed to remain closed?

Comment: @StoneyB: It would certainly help if the OP gave an indication as to what if anything he still wanted clarified after the comments, answer, and pointer to a question addressing the more general point. I just cannot see the point in proliferating questions where there's *sometimes* a different nuance depending on whether you *eat/do/take/touch lunch/lessons/drugs/etc.* Maybe in future I should content myself with just anonymously downvoting things I don't want to see here, rather than continually attempting to persuade the unpersuadable to adopt my viewpoint.

Comment: @Billy: To repeat, I do not think you will find an "authoritative source" distinguishing *do lunch* from, say, *have lunch* or *eat lunch*. But at least if someone goes to the trouble of posting an answer that I disagree with, I might be moved to seek out supporting evidence from actual usage (if that were possible) to back up my natural intuition that my understanding of idiomatic usage generally corresponds with the majority (sometimes, only of **UK** speakers).

Comment: ...in this particular case, consider 366 Google Books hits for ["have lunch to discuss"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+lunch+to+discuss%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as against just 7 for ["do lunch to discuss"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22do+lunch+to+discuss%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you being deliberately difficult? You surely can't seriously expect me, upon stumbling across an answer I disagree with, to immediately start researching and drafting an answer in case the question gets closed in the next half hour. You surely can't consider *good answers to questions* a priority if you happily condone the closure of legitimate questions 8 hours after they're posted with nothing in the way of an answer except one person's intuition. And, *please*, why is that question still closed? It's not a duplicate. Better answers may still come. What are you gaining?

Comment: @Billy: I'd have thought my position was clear by now. I think that question is trivial, and I've no wish to see it or its ilk on ELU. There *might* be something interesting about the more general case of why we tend to use certain verbs with certain connotations, but that's unlikely to emerge from questions like *"What's the difference between doing drugs and taking drugs?"*. Or *“publish in” vs. “publish on”.* Out of politeness, such questions should be answered, but they're unlikely to lead to anything interesting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  How does this differ from [what-exactly-are-the-differences-between-diligent-assiduous-and-sedulous](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94744/)? That question is much better in point of research, but it's the same kind of question. Yes, Robusto posted an answer; for the record, I happen to think it's an adequate answer; but that you and four others have decided that's a final and complete answer and there's nothing more which could possibly said seems hasty to me, and to leave it closed on the grounds that it's an Exact Duplicate is just flat wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP at least thinks it's an interesting question; it is not any more or less specific than any other word usage question; it falls within the scope of ELU; Robusto's answer is unreferenced and contested (by me); the given reason for closure is bogus. These are all facts. I cannot, for the life of me, see by what stroke of illogic this results in the question being closed. *Nothing* about your position is clear to me.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't for one moment suppose I'm 100% consistent in my attitudes. If you followed the link in my comment to *diligent-assiduous-sedulous*, you'll have seen that [George Crabb](http://www.infoplease.com/encyclopedia/people/crabb-george.html) wrote at some length on the matter. Maybe Billy would like to see more such "references", but I must admit I just ended up thinking *"this guy is an anal retentive"*. I don't want to seem rude, but I don't think we're getting anywhere with this whole issue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Crabb's fun; I think his problem is rather a superfluity of leisure than a too-scrupulous discrimination (jeez, he's got me doing it); but I don't think a 200-year-old dictionary's gonna help anybody today except editors of Romantic authors. Don't worry about seeming rude; you always *seem* rude, but you're not. :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "I think that question is trivial, and I've no wish to see it or its ilk on ELU." It would be nice if you and your fellow bullies would found your own website and let the rest of us decide which questions are trivial.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus It's a community. [Gain enough rep](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) within the community and you can vote to re-open closed questions (and the closers cannot re-vote to close).

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: I think that's putting it a bit strong to accuse me of being a bully. Presumably you find my attitude supercilious, and if that's the case I don't suppose I could convince you otherwise. But I do think you should ask yourself *why* the guys who bankroll ELU shovel their money and time into it at all. As Andrew Leach says, ELU *is* a community - but I don't think that's its *purpose* (from, say, [Jeff Atwood's](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/users/91/) perspective). He wants us to create an enduring and sophisticated *knowledge base*, not a downmarket talking shop.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's very rare to find questions on ELU (open or closed) that are any more sophisticated and enduring. In fact, I'd hazard a guess that - from the point of view of someone pumping money into the place - encouraging a community is really important, as it keeps people happy (and hence answering/asking questions). Boring questions are hardly a barrier to a solid knowledge base, but pissing your users off might be in the long run. Questions that are closed without answer but not deleted are enduring, but of no value whatsoever.

Comment: (Not that I want to take part in a community that deletes legitimate questions for being boring, but it would at least be consistent.)

Comment: @Billy *Duplicate* questions which are closed can be left undeleted precisely in order that they endure. Questioners who search the site before asking may find a duplicate and follow the link to the answer; and if they don't search then the system may present a match to them. While what they do (carry on asking or research the found result) is up to them, if that match has been deleted then they certainly can't use it. There are many way of asking a question: preserving duplicates helps find them.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm sorry, I really don't get it. If this question *is* to endure on ELU, then my question remains: why can't we open it and allow it to gather answers? If it is *not* to endure on ELU, as Fumble implied by calling it "trivial", why not get rid of it rather than leaving it pointing at an alleged (but bogus) duplicate and unanswered? If it's contributing to the knowledge base, then surely it would do so better with decent answers. If it's not, it's dead weight.

Comment: @Billy Well, currently the question **is** open, so grab your chance to give the definitive answer!

Comment: @Billy: Where did you get the idea that this question was closed for being _boring_?

Comment: @J.R. It was originally closed because five people wrongly thought it was an exact duplicate and/or answered elsewhere. FumbleFingers explained why he was against its subsequent reopening by describing it as "trivial". What else could FF have meant? It certainly isn't *easy*.

Comment: @Billy: I'm calling you out for saying this: "Not that I want to take part in a community that deletes legitimate questions for being boring..." I don't think this community as a whole deletes questions for being boring, and I don't think such allegations are constructive. Maybe FF said he thought the question was trivial. (What would you call it? Profound?) He's got a right to publicly say how he feels about the question, because you've brought up the subject, but he's just one user, he's not "the community." Also, the question has now been reopened – what else do you want?

Comment: @J.R. (1) That quote was one half of a hypothetical: I would not like it if you were such a community, but it would seem more consistent with the site's aims, as given by FF, if you were. You misunderstood me. (2) The question is neither profound nor trivial. Please don't be ridiculous. (3) Everyone has a right to say how they feel about the question. That's why I started this discussion. I don't understand your objection. (4) 22 hours ago, several days after the question was reopened (and this discussion understandably stopped), *you* addressed *me*. What do *you* want?

Comment: @Billy: What do I want? I'm tired of the rhetoric. "You guys are pseudonymous bullies and cowards. New users are treated like crap. The etiquette here is abnormal... big neon sign saying ‘you are not welcome’. We need to promote discussion, not tell them to shut up. All new visitors feel as though they're treading on eggshells. That user got treated like crap. Just because _you_ think you've provided a perfect and full answer..." If you disagree with a closure, fine, state your case. But stop condemning the community every time you do, stop acting like every closure proves we are all snobs.

Comment: (cont.) We're _not_ a community that closes questions for being "boring," we don't post neon signs saying "YOU ARE NOT WELCOME HERE," and we don't tell people to "shut up." Those are _your_ paraphrases of comments you've read. "Questions that are answerable, don't break rules, etc. should by default be left open, **even if they are stupid or poorly researched**." That may be your philosophy, but it may not be everyone's. You can call people names like Andrew, you can rant about our rudeness like you have been, or you can start leaving comments you think are more polite, and set an example.

Comment: @J.R.: You seem really angry here. Like Billy, I feel the "community" here is often less that communal, definitely not always united, & that _some_ of the high-ranking "experts" are downright rude, unfriendly, & self-righteous in their responses. Setting a good example for insensitive users is a waste of time: They won't notice what they don't know how to see. I don't think Billy's saying that "we're all snobs" -- that's your anger speaking, I believe -- just that a few of us are holier-than-thou. That may be inevitable sometimes. Qs like _Why would you think that?_ are patronizing (2B cont.)

Comment: (cont.)  even though it **seems to be a Q asking for a reason** rather than a slap on the palm with a ruler for not conforming to the rules. Maybe all those impatient experts pining for high-level questions believe that new users somehow enter into an heritable collective unconscious of the the EL&U community. I don't think that happens. I'm still not sufficiently in touch with it myself after 7 months here just about every day.

Comment: @BillFranke: Sorry if I seemed angry; I just haven't appreciated some of the broad-brush accusations over the past couple of weeks. Do we have some users who are hard-headed? Sure we do. Could some exercise a bit more civility? Absolutely. But that's not everyone. That said, you're entirely correct, Billy has _not_ called us snobs, that was me overreacting, and putting words in his mouth. Thanks for calling me out on it. P.S. (to Billy): my apologies.

Comment: @J.R. I understand your frustration, and I'd like to ask you to understand mine. I respect that you know what is good for ELU better than I do, and I expect you to respect that I know the impression new users get of this site better than you do. If new users appear to be ganging up on you, please admit the possibility that they are not a gang, but that they all *individually* see something that you don't! I am coming to realise that the impression I had of ELU - from past experience of message boards and other SEs, the FAQ, etc. - is wrong, though I still don't quite see what's right (cont...)

Comment: and this could explain new users' frustration. All of the snippets you've quoted from me were told from the perspective of a new user: in my experience, mods on (large) forums are often answerable to the majority of their users, who *do* see question closure as a slap on the wrist; questions within the rules *are* left alone; those who post bad questions are *not* welcome. If ELU wants to be different and break tradition, fine, but that should be made clear. Anyway: in *this* discussion, I'm sure you'll see that I've said nothing like what you've quoted, and certainly nothing unreasonable.

Answer (score 3):

The question as it stands has multiple issues. It should be closed until it is edited to show the OP's efforts at research, and until the text in question is expanded to show enough context. Until then, the question is both incomplete and nonconstructive.

As for it being a duplicate, the main objection I've seen is that the existing answers over at the other question are inadequate. That never means we should have duplicate open questions. That means we need a better answer over at the other question.